# why my inner loop iterates less then out loop? very strange?

Tags: c#, linq

for example

```
            foreach(var toCheck in query)
            {
                foreach (var againstItem in totalWeight)
                {
                    count1++
                    if (getIEnumerable(toCheck,againstItem).Any(
                           x => { count2++; return (x == againstItem.Key); }))
                    {
                        blacklist.Add(toCheck);
                        break;
                    }
                    count3++;
                }
            }
```

the results are:
`count1` = 166184
`count2` = 30620
`count3` = 165848

I am expecting `count2` would be much bigger compared to `count1` and `count3`

Comment: What is your question? What results did you expect?

Comment: Its very much dependent on the data

Comment: if GetIEnumerable returns empty in 80% of the cases and 1 element in the other.

Comment: "I am expecting count2 would be much bigger compared to count1 and count2" Why do you expect `count2` to be bigger than itself? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no items to enumerate, the loop will not run and the `count2` will not be increased.

Is that possible in your case?

Answer (score 5):

count2 will be incremented once for each element in the collection returned by getIEnumerable(...), until a match is found in that collection.

If that function returns empty collections, then the count2 can easily be smaller than count1

Answer (score 2):

The condition inside the code block

```
x => { count2++; return (x == againstItem.Key); }
```

is evaluated once *for every item in the list*.

That's the meaning of the `.Any` method- it determines whether any item in the enumeration satisfies the given condition. It must evaluate the condition for each item and see if the result is `true` or `false`. Though once it's found a `true` then execution stops there.

Comment: Not 100% true, because the IEnumerable.Any() will stop iterating once there is an item that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know c# but my guess would be that

`count1` counts all loops, every time

`count2` , does count only as long as it finds a hit. and just like the guy before me just said if you have no elements it doesn't get incremented

`count3` counts the conditions that are not met, so every time a hit is found, it does a break and doesn't do count3++